Oracle Apex Dynamic Action with jquery selector trigger on custom button in map region does not work: No such Action when fired
I have a map region on Oracle Apex 23.2 with a custom info windows. In this window, I want a button to start a Dynamic Action.
This is the HTML code for the button:
<button type="button" class="t-Button t-Button--tiny t-Button--success t-Button--stretch fa fa-location-arrow" data-action="DRIVE_TO_DESTINATION" 
data-appointment_id=&APPOINTMENT_ID. data-latitudine=&LATITUDINE. data-longitudine=&LONGITUDINE. >
    Drive</button>

This method works well in the card region, but in the map region, I get the error in the browser console: "No such action, 'DRIVE_TO_DESTINATION'. Like the DA was not registered.
This is the DA:
[![dynamic action configuration][1]][1]
Any hint?
EDIT:TRIALS USING NEW JS API 22.1
So, i've tried this approach:
I've created on the Execute on Page Load section a little js code to create a new action and register it on my page:
apex.jQuery(window).on('theme42ready', () => {
  apex.actions.add([
    {
      name: 'launch-google-nav',
      Label: 'Launch google maps',
      action: (event, element, args) => {
        $.event.trigger("btn_drive_clicked");

        return true;
      },
    },
  ]);
});

Then i've created the following HTML code to display the button:
<a href="#action$launch-google-nav?latitudine=&LATITUDINE."  class="btn-drive t-Button t-Button--tiny t-Button--success t-Button--stretch fa fa-location-arrow" type="button" 
>Naviga</a>

And finally, the DA:
[![New Da Conf][2]][2]
And finally is working!!!
thank you guys!

The syntax you have used is reserved for the apex.actions framework (docs), introduced in 22.1. It assumes that there is an action defined with the name of the attribute value (DRIVE_TO_DESTINATION). If it is not the error you are seeing is thrown.
Here is the extract from the docs:

Solutions: use another data attribute (eg: data-myaction) OR use a class as jquery selector and derive the data attribute using triggeringelement OR (most modern "apex-way" solution) use the apex.actions framework.
Here and here are a couple of good blogs about the apex.actions API.

Hi, thank you. I've tried also to put the DA on Page 0. Then i see the change in your answer and i checked the new api, but i have no luck also in this way.
I've updated main post with new trials
